# Android Studios Layout Preview Blank

Tags: android-studio

The Android Studios version is 3.0.1

The Layout Preview shows a blank screen, the API Version in the preview shows "null".

[image]

In styles.xml the theme is set to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

I've also tried to open the layout preview like below, but it doesn't work.
View ->Tool Windows -> Preview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to View ->Tool Windows -> Preview

Also, Invalidate caches and Restart Android Studio

Comment: I've also tried to open the layout preview like below, but it doesn't work.
View ->Tool Windows -> Preview 

I've added the screenshot in the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing your parent in Styles as :-

```
parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
```

Full Style will be :-

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```